# Allowing links in Helmets CSP

Tags: node.js, express, discord, ejs, helmet.js

I’ve had issues regarding my CSP header within helmet, where links, no matter what I did, would never work, always would return an error or a broken link, usually both. How would I fix it? Current Code:

```js
app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            directives: {
                ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
                'default-src': ['\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'self\'', '\'https://*\'', '\'http://*\''],
                'script-src': ['\'self\'', '\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'unsafe-eval\'', '*'],
                'img-src': ['\'self\'', '\'https://*\'', '\'http://*\''],
            },
        })
    );
```

Comment: Why bother having a CSP if you're going to allow everything from everywhere?

Comment: @Joe | Because no matter what I did I had to allow content links, I develop around Firefox as an assurance that everything works knowing that firefox is super strict with content allowed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, to start, in basic content security policy headers for major websites, you may see something like the following:
`<meta http-equiv-‘Content-Security-Policy’ content-‘default-src: *, ‘unsafe-inline’;’>`
Well, in helmet, there is a different story,

```
app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            directives: {
                ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
                'default-src': ['\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'self\''],
                'script-src': ['\'self\'', '\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'unsafe-eval\'', '*'],
                'img-src': ['\'self\''],
            },
        })
    );
```

And well I found a fix for those using Express, and EJS to create a link allowing CSP header, which this will include Discord links as well.
——————————————————————————————————————————————
In the basic Content Security Policy header for other websites stated above, you can essentially use the same methods, to allow links, it would be as simple as `https://*`, at least in the normal meta tag, but this is Helmet and Express, so we need to finesse it. Taking the code I have in my question portion, we can fix it up to *actually* allow for basic links.

```js
app.use(
       helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
           directives: {
              app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            useDefaults: false,
            directives: {
                'default-src': ['\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'self\'', 'https://*', 'http://*', '\'unsafe-eval\'', '*'],
                'script-src': ['\'self\'', '\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'unsafe-eval\'', '*', 'http', 'https'],
                'img-src': ['\'self\'', 'http://*', 'https://*', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com'],
            },
        })
    );
```

So, a little explanation.
———
Under the ‘img-src’ we originally see ‘self’, which is allowing images within the code (Such as the src being ‘../../public/img/img.jpg’), those images will show, but we need to add more, especially for links, so we begin working with ‘https://*’, ‘http://*’, and ‘https://cdn.discordapp.com/‘. For the two ‘http(s)://‘ headers, those are any links with a secure connection, or an unsecured connection, from any *regular* domain, nothing from a sub domain as far as I have discovered, so to allow for discord specifically, we use Discord’s image linking system, which is `cdn.discordapp.com`, which allows icons, and server icons to be displayed into your EJS code and webpage. I think that just about covers it, any questions let me know and I will try to answer them!